# iOS Reload the layout of the page on show/hide of components

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface

I have a VC with 4 buttons and 4 tableviews as shown below. I want when I click the button, respective tableview be hidden and the below components come up. And when click the button again the hidden table appears back and below components move down. I am able to hide and show the tableview, but can't make the components to move up or down.

Have created the view in storyboard only. I want to make all tableviews little taller in height, so at least 1-2 cells can accommodate, but if I make them taller all components doesn't fit in a single page and I am not able to access the last components.

**UPDATE** 
On each button click I have method like this to do actions on particular tableview :-

```
- (IBAction)inQueueBtnClicked:(id)sender {
if (self.inQueueListTv.hidden == FALSE)
    self.inQueueListTv.hidden = YES;
else
    self.inQueueListTv.hidden = FALSE;

//[self updateViewConstraints];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
//[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

}
This code shows and hides the tableview.

On hiding a tableview, the below button should be placed in place of tableview and thus other below components move upwards. Basically, if user doesn't want to see for instance 1st and 3rd tableviews, then on clicking 1st and 3rd button the both tableviews gets hidden and other components can accommodate on the same page and get more space on the page.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried in an effort to get the components to move up and down?  Where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: 1. [tableView setHidden:YES] does not work! It is not possible to hide the tableView object from view. You can, however, set its frame to 0, to make it go away. But Your question is not clear. Why do you need 4 tableviews on the same page?!

Comment: Of course you can hide table views! @Tvd, your code is only hiding / unhiding a single table view. Show how you update the entire view and explain what is not working.